# Probability of the product of i.i.d. r.v. with values in $\{-1, 1\}$ is equal to the probability of any member of the product equaling the product

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, induction

Let $(C_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of i.i.d. r.v. with values in $\{-1, 1\}$ by distribution $\mathbb{P}(C_k = 1) = 0.5 = \mathbb{P}(C_k = -1), \forall k$. I'd like to express that the probability of the finite product of the elements of the sequence is equal to the probability of a any member of the sequence. Namely,
$\mathbb{P}(C_1\cdots C_n = a_1\cdots a_n) = \mathbb{P}(C_l = a_1\cdots a_n), a_i \in \{-1, 1\}, \forall l$.

I have already proven the claim when $n = 2$, and I was wondering whether there is some neat trick to finish the induction hypothesis cleanly? While it is obvious that the product is either $-1$ or $1$, and each every member of the product is independent of one another, it feels like cutting corners to just state that and be done with it.

Comment: Use expectation. By independence, if $P$ is any finite product of pairwise distinct elements $\{C_j\}$, then you have $0=\mathbb E[P]=p - (1-p)$, where $p = \mathbb P(P=1)$ and $1-p = \mathbb P(P = -1)$

Comment: @DominikKutek Ah, good observation! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\geq2$:

$$P\left(\prod_{i=1}^nC_i=1\right)=$$$$P\left(\prod_{i=1}^nC_i=1|C_n=1\right)P(C_n=1)+P\left(\prod_{i=1}^nC_i=1|C_n=-1\right)P(C_n=-1)=$$$$P\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}C_i=1\right)\frac12+P\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}C_i=-1\right)\frac12=\frac12$$using independence by second equality.

Of course this is also true for $n=1$.